# How to get correct DataType of DataColumn in empty table?

Tags: database, sqlite, ado.net

I am working on some C# code that creates a new Sqlite database based on a lot of dynamic data and I'm stuck on a part where it is trying to determine if a column needs to be created or altered for new data coming in.

An existing method which processes tables by getting a DataTable and looking at the DataColumn Datatype and size, doesn't seem to work in this process for creating a new table because DataColumn.DataType is always System.Object when under all previous circumstances it has been populated with the correct types used to created the table e.g. string with size 128. It's retrieved with really simple code along the lines of...

```
IDbCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", connection);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
dt.Load (reader);
```

I manually added a row with a single populated column and then voila! it returns string with size 128 correctly. Since it is using the database schema (finding length 128) and not the data from the row I added, why won't it work with an empty table?

Is there a workaround someone can suggest?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so you are not required to use any specific data type when creating tables.
(Reading the column types of a query does not make much sense because you could get value of another type in the same column.)

Comment: That is true for SQLite itself, but ADO.Net will type the DataColumns of the DataTable when created in every other instance where we create a DataTable. For example, you place a text string with 40 characters in a Sqlite database column set to TEXT(32). When ADO.Net tries to create a DataTable for a query including this record/column you will get a failed constraint error from the load. 

It is only when the table is empty that this fails to happen apparently. Even if you use "WHERE 1=2" in a query so it returns no results you get typed DataColumns IF the table contains data.